# How to deal with input parameter containing single quote in between value?

Tags: plpgsql

I have function which take varying character from frontend and return certain computed values, but the issue iam facing is when input value for that parameter contain single quote than its throwing error like procedure does not exist.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE compute(p_company_name character varying DEFAULT NULL::character, INOUT response double precision DEFAULT NULL::double precision)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $procedure$
  begin
  
  select estimate into response from tableA
    where comp = p_company_name;
  
  exception
  when others then select   -1 into response;---other error
  end
   $procedure$
    ;
```

For all input value without quote in it works fine when input value for parameter is like p_company_name = **samsung's** then it throwing error.

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is broken - you use wrong (or you don't use) parameter escaping. Every input should be sanitized by quote escaping:

Input: "Pavel's book" -> Output "Pavel''s book"

```
select foo('samsung's'); -- syntax error
select foo('samsung''s'); -- ok
```

or you can use custom string

```
select foo($$samsung's$$); -- ok
```

You should to read some about SQL injection, because if you see described problem, then your application is SQL injection vulnerable.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, iam completely new to it, its only 1 month into plpgsql

Comment: from front end Iam getting json format like p_company_name = "samsung's"

Comment: @SQLLER - if you enter the value manually, you have to double inner quotes

Comment: i need to handle it from frontend/backend of application? can be handled at plsql side right?

Comment: @SQLLER - you neet to handle it on client side